# Android wear app not installing (using jack compiler)

Tags: android, gradle, apk, wear-os

When I build release apk file and install on my phone, it does not install on my smartwatch. This started happening after I enabled Jack compiler.

Both gradle files (mobile and wear) have jack enabled:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Before I enabled jack, the app was installing normally on my smartwatch. I already tried deleting build folders in project, cleaning the build etc.

Do I need to enable anything else, or does Jack not work at all with android wear?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#known-issues), it is a known issue that [Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run) does not currently work with Jack and will be disabled while using the new toolchain. Also, since Jack does not generate intermediate class files when compiling an app, tools that depend on these files do not currently work with Jack and this might be the cause of your issue.

However, you can file a [bug](http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs) if you find other issues while using Jack.